# When to initiate custom view in UITableViewCell subclass?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to subclass a Cell, but the frame size i get in `init()` is not the one I set in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    initCell()
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initCell()
}
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    println("ContentViewFrame IN SET SELECTED: \(self.contentView.frame)")
}

func initCell() {
    println("ContentViewFrame IN initCell: \(self.contentView.frame)")
}
}
```

I do register it with tabelView:

```
myTable.registerClass(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "awesomeCell")
```

Use it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("conversationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ConversationCell
    return cell
}
```

Set height dynamically:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}
```

This is a console output:

```
ContentViewFrame IN initCell: (0.0,0.0,320.0,44.0)
ContentViewFrame IN SET SELECTED: (0.0,0.0,320.0,99.5)
ContentViewFrame IN SET SELECTED: (0.0,0.0,320.0,99.5)
```

So I would expect the cell to have height of 100.0 when initialised. But it has a height of 44.0 and only `setSelected` function returns correct height. At what stage of cell initialisation I should define my custom init, so I could use the cell with height defined by `heightForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: Why do you need the height in initCell()? Where are you creating your cell view components? It doesn't know the height in init because it's set after cell creation via the delegate method.

Comment: you can put the function in `layoutSubviews()`

Comment: I wouldn't put anything in layoutSubviews unless it was laying out subviews. Need to know what's going on in initCell first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the function in `layoutSubviews()`. You don't put the function there because it is "laying out subviews", but rather because it is the function called in the lifecycle of the cell where you can guarantee that all the subviews of the cell are in fact layed out by the first line of it `super.layoutSubviews()` and thus `contentView.frame` will be defined and accurate. There is no guarantee that `contentView.frame` is accurate in init. A possible place to change frames would be `prepareForReuse()` as it is a place where you can cleanup and customize your cell before it is reused again. It would look like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    myFunction()
}
```